# List of combination between rows of diagonal block matrix

Tags: r, combinations, slice, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following R matrix that is a combination of 2x3 and 3x3 submatrices and it can be more than 2 submatrices with different dimension (e.g. m1xp and m2xp and m3xp where each of m1,m2,m3 <= p)

```
A2 <- list(rbind(c(1,1,1),c(-1,1,-1)),
           rbind(c(-1,1,1),c(1,-1,2),c(2,-1,2)))
library(Matrix)
A2 <- as.matrix(Matrix::bdiag(A2))
Rhs <- matrix(c(0,5,0.5,4),nrow = 4)
beta <- c(rep(1.2,3),c(0.5,0.2,0.1))
> A2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]   -1    1   -1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0   -1    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1   -1    2
[5,]    0    0    0    2   -1    2
```

I would like to get all the rows indices combination between the first sub-matrix and the 2nd sub-matrix to solve an linear optimization problem. The combination has to be from both submatrices then solve for new beta and then check if the condition `Aq %*% beta == Rhs` is satisfy, stop. If not, then take another combination.  I think below is all the rows combination between the sub-matrices:

A combination as one from the first sub-matrix  and one from the second sub-matrix

```
Aq <- A2[c(1,3),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,4),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,5),]
Aq <- A2[c(2,3),]
Aq <- A2[c(2,4),]
Aq <- A2[c(2,5),]
```

Then, a combination as one from the first and 2 from the second matrix

```
Aq <- A2[c(1,3,4),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,3,5),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,4,5),]
Aq <- A2[c(2,3,4),]
Aq <- A2[c(2,3,5),]
Aq <- A2[c(2,4,5),]
```

Then, a combination as one from the first and 3 from the second matrix

```
Aq <- A2[c(1,3,4,5),]
Aq <- A2[c(2,3,4,5),]
```

Then, a combination as 2 from the first and one from the second matrix

```
Aq <- A2[c(1,2,3),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,2,4),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,2,5),]
```

Then, a combination as 2 from the first and 2 from the second matrix

```
Aq <- A2[c(1,2,3,4),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,2,3,5),]
Aq <- A2[c(1,2,4,5),]
```

Then, a combination as 2 from the first and 3 from the second matrix

```
Aq <- A2[c(1,2,3,4,5),]
```

Is there a better way to get all the combinations?
Then I would like to create a loop that choice one on the above combination at a time and check if

```
if (Aq %*% beta == Rhs) {
  break
} else {
  TAKE ANOTHER COMBINATION Aq
}
```

Please note I could have more than 2 submatrices that create the block matrix. Then I have to create all row combinations between from the first, 2nd and 3rd matrix.  I am hoping there is easy way to do in R.  I have tried grid.expand function but it is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what are first block and second block matrices ?

Comment: Looks like `A2` is a sparse matrix, it's a combination of 2x3 and 3x3 submatrices. But I don't understand the question. Can you take a step back and explain some context about what you're trying to achieve? What is `Aq` for and the loop that chooses one of the above combinations, then checks whether `Aq %*% beta == Rhs`? Are you simply searching for the first `Aq` that solves `Aq %*% beta == Rhs`? Are you trying to solve a set of linear equations?

Comment: @YOLO first block matrix is the first matrix on the block diagonal matrix and 2nd block matrix is the 2nd matrix on the block diagonal matrix. Please note the number of columns are the same for matrices in the diagonal  block matrix  and the number of rows can't be more than the columns for each matrix.

Comment: @smci Thank you, you are right I am trying to solve some optimization problem and I need to find the first matrix Aq that solve the linear optimization problem.

Comment: `bdiag` is `Matrix::bdiag`, right? You need to add `library(Matrix)` to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible base R approach:

```
indices1 <- 1:2
indices2 <- 3:5
apply(expand.grid(seq_along(indices1), seq_along(indices2)), 1, 
    function(x) t(apply(
                      expand.grid(combn(indices1, x[1], simplify=FALSE), 
                            combn(indices2, x[2], simplify=FALSE)), 
                  1, unlist)))
```

output:

```
[[1]]
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    4
[5,]    1    5
[6,]    2    5

[[2]]
     Var11 Var12 Var2
[1,]     1     2    3
[2,]     1     2    4
[3,]     1     2    5

[[3]]
     Var1 Var21 Var22
[1,]    1     3     4
[2,]    2     3     4
[3,]    1     3     5
[4,]    2     3     5
[5,]    1     4     5
[6,]    2     4     5

[[4]]
     Var11 Var12 Var21 Var22
[1,]     1     2     3     4
[2,]     1     2     3     5
[3,]     1     2     4     5

[[5]]
     Var1 Var21 Var22 Var23
[1,]    1     3     4     5
[2,]    2     3     4     5

[[6]]
     Var11 Var12 Var21 Var22 Var23
[1,]     1     2     3     4     5
```

---

edit: adding a more general version:

```
#identifying the indices
indices <- split(seq_len(nrow(A2)), max.col(abs(A2) > 0, "first"))

#generating the combinations
apply(expand.grid(lapply(indices, seq_along)), 1L, 
    function(idx) {
        t(apply(
            expand.grid(
                lapply(seq_along(idx), 
                    function(k) {
                        combn(indices[[k]], idx[k], simplify=FALSE)
                    })),
            1L, unlist))
    })
```

Comment: thank you so much for this approach.  Is there a way to identify the indices from A2

Comment: @JesZ, I added a more general version. Pls take a look

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate you help

Comment: if I have this matrix A2 A2 <- as.matrix(bdiag(list(rbind(c(1,1,1),c(-1,1,-1)),
                            rbind(c(-1,1,1),c(1,-1,2))))) the code is not working

Comment: the indices of A2 <- as.matrix(bdiag(list(rbind(c(1,1,1),c(-1,1,-1)),
                           rbind(c(-1,1,1),c(1,-1,2)),
                           rbind(c(-2,1,1),c(1,3,2),c(2,-1,2))
                           )))
is not working

Comment: @JesZ the prev mtd of identifying the indices was not very robust. I have fixed it

Comment: thank you so much.  It really helps this is very nice off you.

Comment: Hopefully the first element of each in all your submatrices is non zero

Comment: what will happens if they are zero? I might have them zero.

Comment: do you have the sub-matrices in a list before u use `bdiag`? or does your problem start with A2? You might want to post some examples. Otherwise it is hard to work with anything without first looking at the patterns

Comment: the block matrix A2 is an argument in a R function that can change based on the requirements of the coefficients. Lets say each sub-matrix is different set of constrains on beta so if beta is (b1,b2 ,b3)  i might need on constrains on the last 2 beta's so the first submatrix would be rbind(c(0,1,-1),c(0,-2,1))

Comment: maybe u can post this as a separate question on how to identify the indices?

Comment: I posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472962/find-the-indices-for-the-sub-matrices-in-block-matrix if you can vote up please