# Find the indices for the sub-matrices in block matrix

Tags: r

This question is following to the question posted

[List of combination between rows of diagonal block matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298621/list-of-combination-between-rows-of-diagonal-block-matrix)

I would like to find the indices for each sub-matrix. The following method

```
indices <- split(seq_len(nrow(A2)), max.col(abs(A2) > 0, "first"))
```

is used but it is not robust since it assumes the first element of each in all the submatrices is non zero but sometimes it could be zero.  I hope someone can help me please find the indices in the case where first element could be zero.

Comment: Are you constructing the A2 matrix from scratch or is it given to you already as a block-diagonal matrix?

Comment: @mastropi given to you in block matrix but the submatrix should have same number of columns but different number of rows